# NodeJS , AngularJS not getting response when on different domain, getting success but without response data

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I developed an application based on MEAN stack and it works fine when UI and api on same domain-port. however , when I segregate UI and api and let say deploying on different domain or even local with different port ,all api call successful but no response data.
FYI I have Access-Control-Allow-Origin * and without that also behaviour is same.

Answer (score 0):

As In case of Cross origin browser first sends an option request. If in response of that OPTION request if  **access-control-allow-origin** found then it sends actual request, else it gives CROS error.

You can add these lines of in app.js of nodeJS code.
This will solve your purpose.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('access-control-allow-headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('access-control-allow-methods', 'POST,HEAD,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.options('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time , but still no luck.
Just to make it more clear , I tried running node on 3000 , UI on 7070  and in UI all the api call pointing to 3000

Comment: here is the screen of request and response  :http://postimg.org/image/4ywljhnmt/
though if both on same server works fine.

Comment: try with `res.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*:*'); `